# CSS Отмена трансформации дочерних элементов

Tags: html, css, css3

```css
div {
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  -ms-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Example</p>
</div>
```

Как отменить транфсформацию тега p, тег p обязательно вложен в div, для которого осуществляется трансформация

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Провернуть обратную трансформацию для дочерних элементов?

```
div p {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: вопрос в том, как вычислить если первый коэфициент 1,3, то есть какая формула?

Comment: обратное число, то есть 1/1.3